# phpthumb zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I can upload the image and resize with phpthumb, but how can i also have the original image uploaded too?

```
     if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {

            // upload the image
            if ($form->station_image->isUploaded()) {
                $form->station_image->receive();
                $station_image = '/upload/images/radio/' . basename($form->station_image->getFileName());
                //upload thumb
                include_once '../library/PhpThumb/ThumbLib.inc.php'; 
                    $thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create($form->station_image->getFileName());                                    
                    $thumb->resize(50, 50)->save($form->station_image->getFileName()); 
                  //thumb ends



            }else{
                echo 'cannot upload'. exit;
            }
```

My forms look like this

```
$station_image->setLabel('Upload File: ')
                        ->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../public/upload/images/radio')
                        ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif')
                        ->addValidator('Size', false, 902400)
                        ->addValidator('Count', false, 1)
                        ->setRequired(false);
```

Please help me how to upload multiple thumbnail or how can i get the original file uploaded as well ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the original image to the constructor of PHPThumb:

```
$thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create($form->station_image->getFileName());
```

So `$form->station_image->getFileName()` is your original file. The problem is you are over-writing the original filename with the resized filename, try this:

```
$thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create($form->station_image->getFileName());                                    
$thumb->resize(50, 50)->save('/path/where/you/want/resized/image/to/go.png');
```

**-- Update --**

Give this a try:

```
if ($form->station_image->isUploaded()) {

    $form->station_image->receive();
    $station_image = '/upload/images/radio/' . basename($form->station_image->getFileName());
    //upload thumb
    include_once '../library/PhpThumb/ThumbLib.inc.php'; 
    $thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create($form->station_image->getFileName());

    // Notice this is using $station_image, which I assume is an accessible path
    // by your webserver                                    
    $thumb->resize(50, 50)->save($station_image); 
    //thumb ends

 }else{
```

**-- Update --**

Try changing this:

```
 $station_image = '/upload/images/radio/' . basename($form->station_image->getFileName());
```

To this:

```
 $station_image = '/upload/images/radio/thumb_' . basename($form->station_image->getFileName());
```

Comment: Thanks but how do i set relative path to save thumbnail ? Please help

Comment: It use to overwrite original image before, now it doesn't even create thumbnail. I am wondering if setting destination in form is causing problem.

Comment: It says File not writeable: /upload/images/radio/thumb_grey.jpg , however i checked there is no permission problem in folder

Comment: There's two paths, the full path, as it exists on the filesystem, and the path relative to the docroot. You need to ensure that the fullpath (/path/to/your/image.png) is accessible by apache user, and that apache user has write privileges to the radio folder.

Comment: another question all of a sudden now even after setting ->setRequired(false); in form I get blank page if i upload no image. I should be able to post without image. Thanks

Comment: The blank page may be some PHP error, try checking your error log and see if there is an issue. Otherwise I agree, you should be able to post without image.